# Is IBM Object Storage S3 have the compatible API with CEPH storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, ceph, object-storage, cloud-object-storage, ibm-cloud-platform

The question, pretty much, says it all, but in order to be more specific on the subject.

A production system is going to using CEPH storage which I know it has RESTful API that is compatible with the basic data access model of the Amazon S3 API.

The issue here is that in order to install a CEPH it requires 3 workers and a lot of resources which I am trying to avoid for the time being.

Has anyone used the IBM Object Storage for the same purpose?

Regards,
Panos

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. AFAIK, **Yes**.

Since I have used Ceph, I know the Ceph Rados Gateway (RGW) object storage service provides a very profound S3 API compatibility. And so does IBM Object Storage S3.
I think you need to check the IBM Spectrum Discover for this purpose.